# Java Json help creating and parsing

Tags: java, json

How to create this kind of json in Java & how to parse it

```
[["Car","Bike","Bus"],["Road","Footpath","Highway"],["Horn","Sound","Pollution"]]
```

Im very new to java. some one please help

Comment: Do you have any code yet?

Comment: Really? None of the thousands of existing questions on SO regarding Java and JSON helped?

Comment: First go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It takes about 10 minutes to learn.  Then understand that there are two types of JSON kits for Java -- those that translate JSON strings to/from "array-like" and "map-like" Java objects, and those that translate to/from arbitrary user-defined Java objects.  (Most other languages only have the former.)

Answer (score 2):

Using [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) Java parser you could create the JSON as

```
JSONArray jsonObj1 = new JSONArray();
jsonObj1.put("Car").put("Bike").put("Bus");

System.out.println(jsonObj1); // ["Car","Bike","Bus"]

JSONArray jsonObj2 = new JSONArray();
jsonObj2.put("Road").put("Footpath").put("Highway");

System.out.println(jsonObj2); // ["Road","Footpath","Highway"]

JSONArray jsonObj3 = new JSONArray();
jsonObj3.put("Horn").put("Sound").put("Sound");

System.out.println(jsonObj3); // ["Horn","Sound","Pollution"]

JSONArray jsonRoot = new JSONArray();
jsonRoot.put(jsonObj1).put(jsonObj2).put(jsonObj3);

System.out.println(jsonRoot);
// prints: [["Car","Bike","Bus"],["Road","Footpath","Highway"],["Horn","Sound","Pollution"]]
```

Deserializing the JSON string is quite simple as well

```
String jsonString = jsonRoot.toString();
JSONArray jsonParsedRoot = new JSONArray(jsonString);
System.out.println(jsonParsedRoot.getJSONArray(0).getString(1)); // Bike
```

Comment: What does it print at the end again? ;)

Comment: @ChrisForrence, thanks for notifying the slip-up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Java EE 7 documentation and examples on this topic: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp.htm